# How to validate knockout data-bind nestings?

Tags: html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Recently ran into a problem where knockout binding to html comments were not well formed because of a nesting problem.  I used where an html comment to house a `ko if:` and then used `ko foreach` which was bound to an html `<div>`, but managed to get the nesting wrong.  Below is an example of the issue:

```
<!-- ko if: isGuestCheckout() -->
     <div data-bind="foreach: formSection()">
<!-- /ko>
Simple malformed knockout</div>
```

In this simple example it is easy to see what the issue is, but in a much larger html block it is much harder to spot the error.  I eventually resorted to have html comments for the end of each knockout binding for example `<!-- end isGuestCheckout() -->` which seems inefficient.

Is anyone aware of a way of validating that knockout data-binds are nested correctly?

Comment: You can often tell it by using proper indentation. Not sure how complicated your bindings are.

Comment: The problem I ran into was that all the html code folding tools do not recognize html comments and would inconsistently fold the comments.  Also indenting only works to a point, when it become impractical to indent any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into similar issues and what I've done to troubleshoot in those cases is add a "whoami" observable for each nested KO-observable object and drop a simple span in the various nested levels to give me some insight as to what is being bound and where.

For example, if I have a view model like this...

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.whoami = ko.observable("I am the root view model");
    self.items = ko.observableArray(); //This holds an array of myItem
};

var myItem = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.whoami = ko.observable("I am an item");
}
```

Then my HTML looks something like this...

```
<div>
    <!-- At this level I expect to see the whoami from the root VM -->
    <span data-bind="text: whoami"/>

    <div data-bind="foreach: listOfItems">
        <!-- At this level I expect to see the whoami from the item -->
        <span data-bind="text: whoami"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing this has helped me quickly discover Knockout nesting issues.  Once I find it then I just pull out the whoami span tags, but I usually end up keeping the whoami observable in the JS in case I need it again.

I hope this helps! :-)